# Android C++ network module with boost asio (ssl), infinite loop

Tags: android, c++, c++11, boost, java-native-interface

I am using boost 1.70.0 in android native for network module.

The AsioClient is singleton for accept http request from all instances(Image, Video, HTML, JS source URI and so on).

And this is not on the main thread for not blocking the main thread.

So I using pthread.h C style thread and ThreadPool is a custom thread pool using pthread.

```
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ssl = asio::ssl;
using tcp = asio::ip::tcp;

// AsioClient.h
class AsioClient {
public:
    AsioClient(AsioClient& client) = delete;
    void operator=(AsioClient const&) = delete;
    static AsioClient& getInstance();

public:
    bool lazyInitialize();

    void send(HttpRequest *request);
    
private:
    AsioClient();
    ~AsioClient();
    static void* networkThread(void* arg);

private:
    static ThreadPool cacheResponseHandlingPool;
    volatile bool needQuit;
    pthread_mutex_t cacheRequestMutex{};
    sem_t quittingSemaphore{};
    boost::asio::io_context ioContext;
    boost::asio::ssl::context sslContext{boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23};
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_{ioContext};
};

// AsioClient.cpp
static pthread_t asioNetworkThread;

static std::deque<HttpRequest*> requestDeque;
static std::deque<HttpResponse*> responseDeque;

static std::deque<std::shared_ptr<AsioSession>> sharedSessionDeque;

ThreadPool AsioClient::cacheResponseHandlingPool;

AsioClient& AsioClient::getInstance() {
    static AsioClient instance;
    return instance;
}

void AsioClient::send(HttpRequest *request) {
    ..
    requestDeque.push_back(request);
    ..
}

void* AsioClient::networkThread(void* arg) {
  auto& client = reinterpret_cast<AsioClient&>(arg);
  do {
    if(!requestDeque.empty()) {
      auto request = requestDeque.front();
      if(request != nullptr) {
          Uri uri = Uri::Parse(request->getUrl());

          // stuck into the https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/boost/asio/detail/service_registry.hpp
          // do_use_service() -> keys_match infinite loop
          auto session_ = std::make_shared<AsioSession>(client.ioContext, client.sslContext, request);
          sharedSessionDeque.push_back(session_);
      }

      requestDeque.pop_front();
    }
  } while(!client.needQuit);
}


// AsioSession.h
#define BIND_2(callback) std::bind(&AsioSession::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)

class AsioSession : public public std::enable_shared_from_this<AsioSession> {
public:
    AsioSession(asio::io_context &ctx, ssl::context& sslCtx, HttpRequest* request)
            : ctx_(ctx)
            , sslCtx_(sslCtx)
            , socket_(ctx, sslCtx)
    {
        currentRequest_ = new HttpsRequest(request); // different with HttpRequest
        resolver_.async_resolve(uri.Host, BIND_2(onResolve)); // look up domain from host (like https://www.google.com)
    }

    void onResolve(const ErrorCode &error, tcp::resolver::iterator iterator) {
        if (error) {
            return;
        }

        socket_.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_none);
        socket_.set_verify_callback(BIND_2(onVerifyCert)); // verify cert

        connect(iterator);
    }

private:
  // ... other method to read, write, handshake, 
  // ... other handle event method for onRead, onWrite, onHandshake ..
private:
    ssl::context& sslCtx_;
    asio::io_context &ctx_;
    ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket_;

    HttpRequest *request_;
    HttpsRequest *currentRequest_;
    asio::streambuf responseBuffer_;
};
```

The problems are:
(1) When making a shared_ptr of AsioSession, stuck in the

```
// boost/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.ipp
execution_context::service* service_registry::do_use_service(
  const execution_context::service::key& key,
  factory_type factory, void* owner)
{
  execution_context::service* service = first_service_;
  while (service)
  {
    if (keys_match(service->key_, key)) // here
      return service;
    service = service->next_;
  }
}

// the problem of infinite loop I guess
bool service_registry::keys_match(
  const execution_context::service::key& key1,
  const execution_context::service::key& key2)
{
  if (key1.id_ && key2.id_)
    if (key1.id_ == key2.id_)
      return true;
  if (key1.type_info_ && key2.type_info_)
    if (*key1.type_info_ == *key2.type_info_)
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

(2) It seems the app killed by the infinite loop.
And even I call the io_context.run(), there is no running async commands.

How can I fix this out? Can you give the insight?

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Note that most asio objects are not threadsafe

Comment: Sorry, I think I should think more this stuff. Thank for your comment.